# Read Request.body with StreamReader can cause Large object heap when reading request in middleware .net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-middleware, large-object-heap

Hi I'm trying to read request inside middleware but I'm facing a strange behavior when reading the (Request.Body) with stream reader !
the problem is that its take a lot of memory for a single request (max 7Mb size )
in my visual studio memory profiler my memory usage rises about 800mb for no reason ! i think its a Large object Heap thing !

any ideas how to solve this strange behavior

Comment: Any code snippet? I mean let us try to reproduce the issue at least.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? like what you have tried so far that did not work. And maybe some code.

Comment: What do you need a 7MB string for? What does this middleware do?